# How to use YAML to create a common node between two functions in Apache Age?

Tags: python, apache-age, opencypher

have two Python functions that each create a Person node in an Apache Age graph. I want to create a common Person node between these two functions that has the same properties. I've been told that YAML can be used to define a common configuration file that can be included in both functions to create or update the common Person node.

My question is: How can I use YAML to define a common configuration file that can be used to create or update a common Person node between my two functions in Apache Age? Specifically, how do I load the YAML file into a Python dictionary, and how do I use the dictionary to set the properties of the Person node in my Apache Age graph?

Here's an example YAML configuration file that defines a common Person node with a name property:

Copy
common_person:
name: John Doe
And here's an example function that creates or updates the Person node in Apache Age using the common_config dictionary:

```
from age import Graph

def update_person_node(common_config):
    graph = Graph("path/to/database")
    with graph.transaction() as tx:
        tx.query(
            "MERGE (p:Person {name: $name}) "
            "SET p += $props",
            name=common_config['common_person']['name'],
            props=common_config['common_person']
        )
```

What is the best way to load the YAML file into a Python dictionary, and how do I use the dictionary to create or update the Person node in my Apache Age graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the example, You can use the `PyYAML` package to load the YAML file into a Python dictionary.

```
import yaml
from age import Graph

def load_yaml(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as yaml_file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
return data

# Use the dictionary to create or update the Person node in your Apache AGE  graph
vertex_id = config_data['id']
vertex_properties = config_data.copy()
del vertex_properties['id']

graph = Graph('path/to/database')
with graph.transaction() as tx:
tx.query(
    "MERGE (p:Person {id: $id}) "
    "SET p += $props",
    id=vertex_id,
    props=vertex_properties
   )
```

This is `load_yaml` function loads the YAML file into a python dictionary. You can then use this dictionary to create or update the person node in your Apache AGE graph.

Answer (score 1):

Install the PyYAML package and import the necessary libraries.

Load the YAML file into a Python dictionary.

```
def load_yaml(file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'r') as yaml_file:
        data = yaml.safe_load(yaml_file)
    return data

# Example usage
config_data = load_yaml('person_config.yaml')
```

Use the dictionary to create or update the Person node in your Apache AGE graph

```
vertex_id = config_data['id']
vertex_properties = config_data.copy()
del vertex_properties['id']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the YAML library. Install it by pip

```
pip install pyyaml
```

and this is the official library documentation: [Pyyaml Documentation](https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation)

follow the link to reach more about it: [Python YAML: How to Load, Read, and Write YAML](https://python.land/data-processing/python-yaml) have a lot of implementations about this library in this link.

to use the dictionary for doing CRUD operations I think that you have to search about an other library to connect them (dictionary and APACHE AGE graph)

Answer (score 0):

The way yo can use YAML to define a common configuration file is as follows:

1. Install PyYAML using the following command:

   pip install PyYAML
2. Configure and create the YAML file using and name it using the common person node configuration.
3. Load the YAML file into a python dictionary and lastly, update the APACHE AGE node using the configurati0on you made in the python dictionary.